# How install .deb file generated by building custom kernel onto virtual machine?

Tags: linux-kernel, deb

I have build a custom kernel and now I want to run this custom kernel on the virtual machine.

What is the way to do so?

I can see that it looks for `.iso` file. However, the generated file is `.deb` file for the kernel I have built.

Comment: If it is a valid deb package try to install it, see if it works

Comment: There's not enough information in your question for a comprehensive answer.  What distribution is your OS?  Debian, Ubuntu, Mint or something different.  Do you know which boot loader you are using (Grub?).  Do you have access to the boot menu when the virtual machine starts, or is it a host virtual machine (eg: in AWS EC2?).  Please [edit] your question to add this information.

Answer (score 0):

Install Debian on your virtual machine. Then transfer your deb file and install it.
Hopefully the deb package will manage the bootloader entries. Reboot and pick your kernel version in the boot menu.